# Schedule Notification Using Push Sharp in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, pushsharp

I have created a Push Notification service for my IOS app using the code from the link below.
http://woutercx.com/2013/05/09/sending-push-notifications-iphone-with-pushsharp-csharp-monotouch-client-server-side/

I have coded every thing and set up the certificates correctly for  push notification in my IOS app.

The question is how do I schedule the push notification to be sent to the registered IOS devices periodically. Lets say I want my users to be notified every hour? In short i do i make use of the methods of Pushsharp to schedule a Remote notification at a specified intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `pushsharp` is a library, not a service, it has no ability to send notifications periodically or delay them. The library is only able to communicate to APNS (apple push notification service). APNS does *not* provide the ability to delay/repeat notifications, so neither does the library.

If you need to send notifications basing on time (say, hourly), you have to set up *your own* service that will wake up hourly and post a notification to devices that need it. I'm afraid there is no other way to do it without external services.